# ElasticSearch and Asp.net Core 2.0

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

For one of my Asp.net core 2.0 project I want to use ElasticSearch, I am not able to find any help. Does it support, If yes can please help me out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch.NET and NEST are the two official .NET clients for Elasticsearch.

Documentation on how to use either can be found in elastic's docs:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/introduction.html